# sed first n occurrences result set between 2 tags / patterns

Tags: sed, xml

I have a big XML file and I get all occurrences between 2 tags:

Here is what I do:

```
sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml
```

And I need to filter to get only first N occurrences.
I've tried with l param but it was not enough :(

So any one knows how to get N matched occurrences from all resultset?

For Example. Here the xml file content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
</root>

 sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml
```

returns all  elements.

So the goal is to filter to get the First n matched patterns ( Elements are multi-line)
If n  = 2 then result =:

```
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
```

Comment: Sample input and an expected output would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really should be using a parser for this, but, just so you know, `sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml` gets you all elements because you `p`rint them all. That command works by addressing all lines between a line containing `<tag>` and the next line in input that contains `</tag>`. Since that makes pretty much all of your lines, just `p`rinting them doesn't show up much of a difference. Something like the following might be a little nearer to the mark:

```
sed -n '\|<tag>|{:n
    \|</tag>|!{N;bn}
    y|\n| |;p
}'
```

It addresses `<tag>` lines and checks them for `</tag>`. If they don't contain the closing string it pulls in another line - and it does so repeatedly until the pattern space contains `<tag>.*</tag>[^\n]*$`.

Then I just translate all `\n`ewline characters in pattern space into spaces.

Here it is again:

```
sed -n '\|<tag>|{:n;\|</tag>|!{N;bn};y|\n| |;p}' <<\DATA
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
</root>
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<tag>  <t1>john</t1>  <t2>john</t2>  <t3>john</t3> </tag>
<tag>  <t1>john</t1>  <t2>john</t2>  <t3>john</t3> </tag>
<tag>  <t1>john</t1>  <t2>john</t2>  <t3>john</t3> </tag>
<tag>  <t1>john</t1>  <t2>john</t2>  <t3>john</t3> </tag>
```

Now you might do:

```
sed -n '\|<tag>|{:n
    \|</tag>|!{N;bn}
    y|\n| |;p
}' ./file | 
sed 's|> |>\n|g;2q'
```

...which gets me:

```
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
<tag>
 <t1>john</t1>
 <t2>john</t2>
 <t3>john</t3>
</tag>
```

Comment: @TVart - while I appreciate the vote of confidence, Stephane's method is, admittedly, faster. It requires only the one `sed` process and doesn't need to loop through the file twice. I definitely recommend you get the hang of the `:label;/address/!{N|H;b label}` idea if you're going to be doing multiline addressing, but his method implements a `h`old space counter along the lines of what you'll find in some of the most advanced `info sed` examples and quits the file as soon as possible. Best, in my opinion, would be a combination of the two.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
xmllint --xpath '//tag[position()<=2]' file.xml
```

Or:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//tag[position()<=2]' file.xml
```

Or:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//tag[position()<=2]' -c . -n file.xml
```

If you wanted to do it with `sed` only you could do something like:

```
sed -n '
  1{x;s/^/../;x;}; # initialise counter with two tokens
  /<tag>/,/<\/tag>/ {
    p; /<\/tag>/{
      x;s/.//;/./!q;x; # remove a token and quit if hold space empty
    }
  }' file.xml
```

That is, use the *hold space* as a counter of remaining sections to display (using dot characters).

Comment: `xmlstarlet` with parameter from the command line: `xmlstarlet sel -t --var n=3 -c '//tag[position() < $n + 1]' file.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want,

```
sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml | head -10
```

Try the below command to get the first two lines which starts with `<tag>`,

```
$ sed -n '/^<tag>/p' file.xml | head -2
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
```

Comment: unfortunatly this did not do expected behaviour.
What is required is to get the first n occurrencies of contents includigs tags, your solution return only the first 10 lines starting at the first occurrence

Comment: please explain your question clearly with an example.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
<tag><t1>john</t1></tag>
</root>

sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml returns all <tag> elements.

I want to get First n Elements

Comment: post the above comment in your question.

Comment: @user70355 see my edit.

Comment: This will not resolve my problem as the node can be multiline. ( I've just updated my initial question )

Comment: But there is no `<t2>,<t3>` tags in your xml file.

Comment: example updated to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe through head -**N**. After the first N occurrences, head exits and thus sed will stop.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `sed` matches are always greedy i.e. `/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/` will match from the first instance of `<tag>` to the last instance of `<\tag>` - including any other XML objects between.

If your version of `awk` supports multi-character record separators, you might be able to do something like

```
awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{RS="</tag>\n";ORS=RS} NR<=n'
```

but really a more robust solution would be to use a dedicated XML parser - for example a very minimal implementation using python's `minidom`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('file.xml')
taglist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('tag')
for i in range(2) :
        print taglist[i].toxml()
```

Comment: Your command should be `awk 'BEGIN{RS="</tag>\n";ORS=RS} NR<=2' c | sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p'` so that it would remove the first two lines.

Comment: Well, if it needs to pass by a script, I already have a solution using XMLReader in php, but the challenge for me was to do it in commande-line tool like sed or awk

Comment: On a line, yes, `sed` is greedy. But multi-line addresses aren't - -it wouldn't make sense. `sed` doesn't know what's in the next input line - or even whether it is the last line - until it is read, so it takes the first available match for `//,/address2/` that it can.

Answer (score 0):

Well, eventually I'll answer myself to my own question.

The solution I've found works in 2 ( maybe 3 ) Steps :

1 - Getting all Required Element by :

```
sed -n '/<tag>/,/<\/tag>/p' file.xml > selectedItems.xml
```

2 - Getting the N-th position of the last item  by

```
POS = grep -n '</tag>' ./selectedItems.xml | head -n [POS] | tail -n 1
```

3 - Getting First N Required Items :

```
sed -n 1,[POS]p selectedItems.xml > selectedItems.xml
```

Of course it is possible to do all steps without splitting, but It wont be such clear.

P.S.
To be sure that the position corresponds to the real N-th position in the tree ( when xml file is formed all in-line ) I used to use:

```
xmllint --format ./myxmlfile.xml
```